# Set configuration of NSURLSession sharedSession

Tags: ios, nsurlsession

I needed to set custom user agent string to sharedSession of NSURLSession. i.e. whenever I call `[NSURLSession sharedSession]`, it will by default contain my custom configuration and I won't need to set it every time.

I can set the configuration to session as,

```
NSURLSession * session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSString * userAgent  = @"My String";
session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = @{@"User-Agent": userAgent};
```

But I cannot find how to set the configuration to `sharedSession` that can be used anytime in code.

Comment: I am in same situation, I need to change some access tokens in configuration after a new user logs in. So did you find any way to change, and yes I read the answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Thats because you cannot modify the sharedSession. Imagine as if the sharedSession is the iOS device sharedSession and is used by all other Apps and frameworks. Makes sense for it to be non-configurable right? The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLSession/sessionWithConfiguration:delegate:delegateQueue:) about it states:

> The shared session uses the currently set global NSURLCache,
>   NSHTTPCookieStorage, and NSURLCredentialStorage objects and is based
>   on the default configuration.

What you want to do is define a custom configuration meaning you will need your own session objects with its own configuration. Thats why there is a specific constructor giving you what you need:

```
+ (NSURLSession *)sessionWithConfiguration:(NSURLSessionConfiguration *)configuration
                                  delegate:(id<NSURLSessionDelegate>)delegate
                             delegateQueue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue
```

For brevity you can use `[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]` to create a basic configuration and then set the additional headers there.

Naturally you will be responsible for retaining the session etc

Answer (score 2):

I was also stuck in this issue, I had to change Authorization in httpHeaders. Daniel answer is right we can't change NSURLSession and its configuration once set. Solution is to set headers in NSMutableURLRequest object like

```
var request = NSMutableURLRequest()
request.setValue("YourAccessToken", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
```

Answered it might help someone.

Answer (score 2):

As per @Daniel Galasko: 
I added following: (just updating as its swift 2.3 code)

```
let sessionConfiguration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
let additionalHeadersDict = ["User-Agent": "User name that you want",
                             "Accept-Language":"lamguages",
                             "Accept-Encoding": "Encoding type" ]
sessionConfiguration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = additionalHeadersDict
```

Thanks again to @Daniel Galasko. Please vote up his answer if you find mine useful.